# Oracle Unique Constraint - Mixed Case

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, oracle11g, constraints

I have an Oracle table that has the following columns:

```
ID
FUNCTION_ID
FUNCTION_ROLE
```

The ID column is unique (sequence) but I also want both (FUNCTION_ID, FUNCTION_ROLE) combination to also be unique.

My query is though, as the FUNCTION_ROLE is a string and the value can be mixed case, what is the best approach to prevent this from happening, i.e.:

```
Data for this table:
Row 1: 1,1,TEST1
Row 2: 2,1,Test1
```

I would expect to get a unique constraint violation when trying to insert Row 2 as ‘Test1’ is the same as ‘TEST1’ – just the case is different.

How can I prevent this as one approach I was thinking was creating another column called FUNCTION_ROLE_UPPER and using this column along with FUNCTION_ID to check for uniqueness – would this be the correct approach?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve this using function-based index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX YOUR_TABLE_U1 ON YOUR_TABLE(FUNCTION_ID, UPPER(FUNCTION_ROLE))
```

Under Oracle 11, you can also consider putting `UPPER(FUNCTION_ROLE)` in a virtual column.

Comment: thanks @Branko - understand the function-based index part but don't understand the virtual column aspect? Can you pls explain/provide example. Thanks.

Comment: @tonsils The idea is essentially the same, except the `UPPER(FUNCTION_ROLE)` also has a name, can be queried just as any normal column and a _true_ UNIQUE constraint can be created on top of it, which allows a FOREIGN KEY to reference it (which would not be possible with just a UNIQUE INDEX).